# Dependency Injection Framework for PCL(WP7.5,RT)

Tags: windows-phone-7, dependency-injection, windows-runtime

I'm creating a project targeting Windows Phone 7.5 and RT.
I want to use some Dependency Injection framework. 
Already tried SimpleIoC from MVVMLight combined with Microsoft's ServiceLocation, but it was too slow.

After some research I decided to go with [fFastInjector](http://ffastinjector.codeplex.com/), but unfortunately it doesnt work with WP7.5. Tried adding ExpressionVisitor implementation found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx), but there are still methods missing in Expression class available in wp7: Assign, Block and Variable.

Is there any workaround to make fFastInjector work in wp7.5?

Is there any comparably fast framework that can handle such project setup?

**EDIT:**

I have found [Portable IOC](https://portableioc.codeplex.com/), which seems to be just what I need. However I'm bit affraid of using solution with only 300 nuget downloads. Does anyone have any expierience with it?

Comment: Autofac and Ninject support both WP7 and WinRT. Autofac is the fastest of the two.

Comment: Basing on http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison ninject is not an option. I'll give Autofac a shot

Comment: That's the blog I based my previous comment on :-)

Comment: This post is great:) I'm bit affraid of using Container with performance worse than fast, since wp7 performance is not that great

Comment: I would say that in most cases performance this isn't that relevant, and do note that the benchmarks on that article are _only_ done on the full .NET version. The benchmarks could different widely for WinRT and WP. You should test this yourself, but you'll have to determine what 'fast enough' is for your application, before starting such benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ninject? That is easy to configure and supports context sensitive binding and convention over configuration. There is package for Ninject for windows 7 .
[Ninject Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.WP7)

Comment: I checked it out, but it seems to be quite slow in comparison with other frameworks.